24.04 wireless issue
I'm a Ubuntu lightweight but I've done several Ubuntu loads of various versions of Ubuntu and the prevailing theme seems to be onboard wireless adapters never seem to work right out of the gate. I always have to hunt for a fix to get onboard wireless adapters to work. I inserted a wireless usb device and it works properly but can't get onboard working. I have tried this on my latest "project" computer a MacBook pro mid 2010 which I think has a Broadcom wireless adapter. I get on websites for a fix but always seem to get led down a path of despair. I was able to get 18.04.6 MATE to work properly with using only 2 Terminal prompt commands. Maybe I should have called it good but I decided to tempt fate and now cannot get 24.04 onboard wireless working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You in advance.
Tom Bell.

No version of Ubuntu has ever been called 18.4 or 24.4. Please edit the question and correct the version info.
